# foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type public definition for 'getenumerator'

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

```
Task03Entities.Entites entities = new Task03Entities.Entites();

// Creat a object for my entites class
Task03BAL.BAL bal = new Task03BAL.BAL();

// creat a object of BAL to call Get Data Method
List<Task03Entities.Entites> entitiesList = new List<Task03Entities.Entites>();

// make a list of class Entities
entitiesList = bal.GetData(entities);

// store data in list
ViewState.Add("Products", entitiesList.ToArray());

// use view state to store entitieslist
Task03Entities.Entites[] entitiesArray =(Task03Entities.Entites[])ViewState["Products"];
List<Task03Entities.Entites> ViewStateList =new List<Task03Entities.Entites(entitiesArray);

// so now ViewStateList contain entitieslist data
// Now the Problem which i am facing is 
if (Request.QueryString["count"] != null) // this is okay
{
  listCount =Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["count"]);   
}

for (int i = (listCount * 2)-2; i < listCount * 2; i++)
{
  Task03Entities.Entites newViewStateList = new Task03Entities.Entites();
  newViewStateList = ViewStateList[i];

// view state contain a list of data here on above line m trying to acess single data
%>
<table>
<%                  

foreach (Task03Entities.Entites item in newViewStateList)
// on above line i am getting following error message
```

> Compiler Error Message: CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on
>   variables of type 'Task03Entities.Entites' because
>   'Task03Entities.Entites' does not contain a public definition for
>   'GetEnumerator'

Comment: What is `ViewStateList`?

Comment: its a list which conatin ViewState Data ... actually first i fetch all data from database then store it in a viewstate the copy the viewstate data into ViewStateList

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's simple: `Task03Entities.Entites` is not a collection.

You initialize an object here:

```
Task03Entities.Entites newViewStateList = new Task03Entities.Entites();
```

And then attempt to iterate over it as if it were a collection:

```
foreach (Task03Entities.Entites item in newViewStateList)
{

}
```

I suspect you want something like:

```
List<Task03Entities.Entites> newViewStateList = new List<Task03Entities.Entites>();

foreach (Task03Entities.Entites item in newViewStateList)
{
    //code...
}
```

Comment: Actually i wanna get specific Items from ViewStateList and then store it newViewstateList . For example there are total 6 items in ViewStateList and i wanna get  single item one bye one through for loop and then display each item through foreachloop beacuse each item contain many fileds like ID FirstName LastName ect ...

Comment: Irrelevant - `newViewStateList` is not a collection **you can't iterate over it** - this is the cause of your error.

Answer (score 2):

Considering message your type  `Task03Entities.Entites` is not a collection and/or not enumerable type. So in order to be able to use `foreach` on it, you have to make it such.

For example can have a look on: [How to make a Visual C# class usable in a foreach statement](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322022/en-us)

Answer (score 1):

just add 
@model IEnumerable
int the first line instead of your regular @model line