# Iteration cannot operate on variables of type public definition for 'getenumerator'

Tags: c#, json, serialization, foreach, deserialization

I am doing a search in which I am making an API call and get the XML response and SerializeXmlNode and DeserializeObject to my root object. Now the problem is when I tried to loop with foreach.

I get this error below:

**foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type (Model.AccountLite) because does not contain public instance definition for 'getenumerator'**

I have inspected this  **data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);**   and i can see the data.

I have tried to look at this [previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462554/foreach-statement-cannot-operate-on-variables-of-type-public-definition-for-get)

Search API call

```
    public static List<AccountLite> searchAccounts(string searchString)
    {
        List<AccountLite> result = new List<AccountLite>();
        Root data = new Root();

        string[] contains = searchString.Split(' ');
        RestClient client = new RestClient(baseUrl);

        foreach (string contain in contains)
        {
            if (contain.Length < 3) continue;

            RestRequest request = new RestRequest($"/xx/xx/xx/xxx/xxx/account?xx=Lite&searchString={searchString}");
            String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);

            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            string requestResponse = response.Content;

            //Converting data from XML into Json and deserializet json object
            try
            {
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.LoadXml(requestResponse);
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
                data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (data?.SiebelMessageEnvelope?.ListOfAccountLite?.AccountLite == null)
                continue;

            //this line is the one showing error.
            foreach (AccountLite item in data.SiebelMessageEnvelope.ListOfAccountLite.AccountLite)
            {
                bool containsBoth = true;
                foreach (string contain2 in contains)
                {

                    if (!item.Name.ToLower().Contains(contain2.ToLower()) && !item.Id.ToLower().Contains(contain2.ToLower()))
                        containsBoth = false;
                }
                if (containsBoth)
                {
                    if (result.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == item.Id) == null)
                    {
                        result.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Model

```
    public class AccountLite
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string AccountStatus { get; set; }
        public string AccountTypeCode { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SRIntegrationFlag { get; set; }
    }

    public class ListOfAccountLite
    {
        public AccountLite AccountLite { get; set; }
    }

    public class SiebelMessageEnvelope
    {
        [JsonProperty("@xmlns")]
        public string Xmlns { get; set; }
        public ListOfAccountLite ListOfAccountLite { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public SiebelMessageEnvelope SiebelMessageEnvelope { get; set; }
    }
```

Json Object

```
 {

 "SiebelMessageEnvelope":{
  "@xmlns":"",
  "ListOfAccountLite":{
     "AccountLite":{
        "Id":"",
        "AccountStatus":"",
        "AccountTypeCode":"",
        "Location":"",
        "Name":"",
        "SRIntegrationFlag":""
     }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ListOfAccountLite` just contains a single `AccountLite`. It doesn't make sense to `foreach` over a single object, where that object is not enumerable (meaning: implemented `IEnumerable[<T>]` or contains an explicit `GetEnumerator()` method).

There's only one object, so... just take it. Instead of

```
if (data?.SiebelMessageEnvelope?.ListOfAccountLite?.AccountLite == null)
                continue;

foreach (AccountLite item in data.SiebelMessageEnvelope.ListOfAccountLite.AccountLite)
{
    // ... do the thing
}
```

simply

```cs
var item = data?.SiebelMessageEnvelope?.ListOfAccountLite?.AccountLite;
if (item is null)
    continue;

// ... do the thing
```

---

That said: you should probably investigate whether `ListOfAccountLite` in the JSON etc is meant to be an *array* rather than a single object.

Comment: Should i repace the whole foreach with?  var item = data?.SiebelMessageEnvelope?.ListOfAccountLite?.AccountLite; and continue if item is not null ?

Comment: Can you also guide me to change ListOfAccountLite to a list so that i can have two options, single results and list of results

Comment: @ITForward having something that can *either* be a list *or* a single result is frankly a terrible API approach; the only "correct" fix there is for it to *always* be a list that may contain zero, one, or many elements; in JSON terms: `"ListOfAccountLite":[{...}]`

Comment: Can we please change ListOfAccountLite of a list, which means it will return a list of accounts

Comment: @ITForward yes, absolutely... *if* you also change the JSON accordingly; the JSON shown can only convey a single account

Comment: I am getting the JSON from API response which gives me data and I can't change it unless I put a request from another team. Can you help me to change the current JSON to return a list? this will help me to test and then motivate my request based on the result i will present.

Comment: @ITForward no: the current JSON *isn't* a list. Talk to the people who are providing the API; the error is theirs